# Delphi: how to create a "thumb" which can sit above the vertical scrollbar?

Tags: delphi

MS Word has such a feature:

[image: Word thumb above scrollbar]

Small rectangle is shown above vert scrollbar and is clickable.
I want to add such thumb above vertical scrollbar of my TMemo descendant, for example. How can I? I need to handle click on such thumb - show split screen (show 2nd memo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word constructs this form in a custom fashion - it separately adds the thumbs and the scrollbar to the window. To emulate this behaviour in VCL you would have to do the same - instead of instantiating a TMemo, make a custom control containing the memo, and a regular scroll bar, and use positioning to put a tiny button above the scrollbar with the same width.

Comment: +1 but fair warning for OP: it's much easier said than done, especially if not familiar with writing controls.